# WordPress custom admin login page

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how to update the `.htacesss` file for a WordPress site? I must change the `wp-admin` login URL to something custom because someone is trying to **brute force hack** into my website right now (on Christmas day!) and therefore I'm trying to hide my login page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Current url:

example.com/wp-admin

Expected url:

example.com/someslug

Comment: There are a ton of plugins to do this for you, as well as provide automatic lockouts, etc. When dealing with these brute force attacks, don't reinvent the wheel.  I use Wordfence a all of my WP installs - https://docs.wordfence.com/en/Wordfence_Official_Documentation

Answer (score 0):

**Change URL using plugin**

This plugin will hide WordPress Admin (/wp-admin/) when a user isn't logged in. If a user isn't logged in and they attempt to access WP Admin directly, they will be unable to and it will return a 404. It can also rename the login URL.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/lockdown-wp-admin/

**Change using a code**

apply filter in admin_url.

```
return apply_filters('admin_url', $url, $path, $blog_id);
```

**Note : If you are using a wordefence or wp security kind plugin then there is already option.**

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't recommend you to edit the .htaccess for the purpose. You can try this code, it works for me.

This code redirects to homepage whenever the default /wp-admin or /wp-login is accessed. You can set a passcode as the login URL and only allow wp-admin and wp-login access via this URL: https://www.yourdomain.com/?you-set-your-passcode

Add this code to the **functions.php** of your theme.

```
// define and set passcode that serves as login url.
define('PASSCODE','make-you-own-passcode');

function mask_login_url(){
// redirect to login page when passcode is verified
if( !is_user_logged_in() && parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY) == PASSCODE ){
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url('wp-login.php?'. PASSCODE .'&redirect=false') );
    exit();
}
// redirect to dashboard if user has already logged in
if( is_user_logged_in() && parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY) == PASSCODE ){
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url("wp-admin") );
    exit();
} } 
add_action( 'init', 'mask_login_url');

function mask_login_redirects(){
if( isset($_POST['passcode']) && $_POST['passcode'] == PASSCODE) return false;

// redirects to dashboard when /wp-admin is accessed and user is logged in
if ( (is_user_logged_in()) && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false)) {
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url("wp-admin"), 302 );
    exit();
}
// redirects to homepage when /wp-admin or /wp-login is accessed and user is not logged in
if ( (!is_user_logged_in()) && ((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false) || (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login') !== false)) && ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PASSCODE) === false ) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
    exit();
}
// redirect to homepage after logout
if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'action=logout') !== false ){
    check_admin_referer( 'log-out' );
    wp_logout();
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url('?logged-out'), 302 );
    exit();
} }
add_action( 'login_init', 'mask_login_redirects', 1); 

// Add a passcode hidden field to login form
function custom_login_hidden_field(){
echo '<input type="hidden" name="passcode" value="'. PASSCODE .'" />';
}
add_action('login_form', 'custom_login_hidden_field');
```